# Group in Linq with Max: How do I get the full data set of the max value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

what I have got so far is this:

```
var a = from e in tcdb.timeclockevent
        group e by e.workerId into r
        select new { workerId = r.Key, Date = r.Max(d => d.timestamp) };
```

This Query is giving me latest "timestamp" of every workerId (Note: workerId is not the primary key of tcdb.timeclockevent). So it is only giving me pairs of two values but I need the whole data sets

Does anybody know how I can get the whole datasets of tcdb.timeclock with the maximal timestamp for every workerId?

OR

Does anybody know how I can get the Id of the data sets of the maximal date for each worker?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `new { workerId = r.Key, Date = r.Max(d => d.timestamp), AllData = r };` ?

Comment: Try following : var a = (from e in tcdb.timeclockevent
        group e by e.workerId into r
        select new { workerId = r.Key, Date = r.Max(d => d.timestamp) })
        .GroupBy(x => x.workerId).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your `r` grouping by `timestamp` and select the first one

```
var a = from e in tcdb.timeclockevent
        group e by e.workerId into r
        select r.OrderByDescending(d => d.timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: is there maybe a more efficient way to do this? I´m getting a time out exception. When I run the following query it gives me the same result and it only needs a few seconds. Any idea?

Comment: select timeclockevent.id, timeclockevent.workerId, max(timeclockevent.timestamp)  from timeclock.timeclockevent group by workerId;

Comment: @BeardyBear - Do you have a composite index (`workerId`, `timestamp` desc)?

Comment: I just found out that it´s not giving me the same result. Sorry

Comment: I mean my SQL query is actually wrong. The id´s aren´t the real id´s of the timestamp

Comment: I think it is just giving me a random id instead of the id that refers to the timestamp

Comment: I´m doing it totally different now. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know how I can get the whole datasets of tcdb.timeclock with the maximal timestamp for every workerId?

Well, the straightforward query would be like this:

```
var queryA =
    from e in tcdb.timeclockevent
    group e by e.workerId into g
    let maxDate = g.Max(e => e.timestamp)
    select new { workerId = g.Key, events = g.Where(e => e.timestamp == maxDate) };
```

If you don't need `IQueryable<T>` result and since there is no SQL construct that returns directly the grouped result set, you could try the following query, which uses a different way of filtering the records with maximal timestamp for every workerId inside the database, and then does the grouping in memory:

```
var queryB = tcdb.timeclockevent
    .Where(e => !tcdb.timeclockevent.Any(e2 =>
        e2.workerId == e.workerId && e2.timestamp > e.timestamp))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(e => e.workerId);
```

You can try and see which one performs better with your data.